# Command-line tool to analyze devices in pre-captured wifi traffic

Tags: command-line, wifi

Goal:

I'm looking for a command-line based tool, that will analyze wifi traffic in pcap files and give me a summary of all the networks, the associated clients and the clients that sent probe requests.

Requierments:

It should

- accept pcap files with wifi-mgmt frames
- not mess around with the original timestamps or use the current time, but will preserve the timestamps from the pcap
- output easily parsable lists of all networks, their connected clients, probe-requests etc.
- run non-interactively and can be automated (preferably on linux)

I've tried utilizing tshark, kismet and airodump-ng. I've especially liked the output of airodump, but it's painful to automate because it only runs interactively (also, it replaces timestamps). Kind of nice is wireshark's wifi statistics in the gui, but they're not available in tshark.

I'm not really interested in the traffic data itself, like IPs and ports. My focus is on the devices themselves and which network they're connected to or which networks they're probing.

Any thoughts or suggestions?